How to find the sides and then the corners of an pointcloud plane, that is not always fully visible
I have a pointcloud, that is segmented into different planes. I have found the correct plane in the pointcloud now I want the corners of the plane. The problem is that this plane is not always fully visible (corners can be missing) or it can also be on an angle.
I already found the contour lines of the plane by first projecting the points on a flat surface and then getting the convexhull. Then some thresholding to find not to small of lines. After that neighboring lines are combined if the angle of the lines are small enough.
All of this results in a set of lines around the plane, but now I need to determine the which lines are the real sides of the rectangle.
Here are some images from the current problem.
Partial Angled Plane
Good Plane
I already tried to find the angle between lines and then seeing if there are 4 to form a rectangle or square.

If I understand well, you want to find the corners of a rectangle that bound your pointcloud? What are the constraints on this rectangle (minimal area, axis aligned, etc.)? The boundaries in your "Good Plane" image do not make a rectangle and there are points that are clearly outside.

The plane is of a screen (with a sound bar below it) and I know the size of the plane, but I want to find the corners of the plane and then use it to calibrate a lidar and camera pair.
Currently, I have it solved by picking the 4 biggest lines and then seeing if they are all on a (almost) 90-degree  angle and it gets the the sides and ignores/skips the partial planes
But now the sides are sometimes too small, and it is more of a trapezoid.
I know some points are outside of the plane but is not the biggest issue
